# error usando la librería go-mysqldump

Tags: go

Estoy usando la librería de https://github.com/aliakseiz/go-mysqldump

y me está arrojando este error con una tabla determinada

```
Error dumping: template: mysqldumpTable:9:3: executing "mysqldumpTable" at <.CreateSQL>: error calling CreateSQL: sql: expected 4 destination arguments in Scan, not 2
template: mysqldumpTable:9:3: executing "mysqldumpTable" at <.CreateSQL>: error calling CreateSQL: sql: expected 4 destination arguments in Scan, not 2
```

Revisando la 'Tabla' en cuestión que tiene la falla, veo que en lugar de ser una Tabla, es una Vista.

Si alguno de ustedes ya se topó con este error y pudo solucionarlo le pido pueda aportar la ayuda.

Sino si alguien conoce otra librería mejor que esta , Bienvenidas las sugerencias !

Saludos y Gracias